# Problem with Crassula Tetragona

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, leaves, succulents

I recently adopted this [Crassula Tetragona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crassula_tetragona) plant from a friend. It's dropping leaves like crazy. This plant is in a south facing window in San Diego, CA.

I haven't repotted it so I'm not sure about the soil mix it's in. There are both brown dried up leaves and green leaves falling.

Could this be due to overwatering? Lack of sunlight?

[image: full plant]

[image: close up of leaves]

[image: root offshoots]

Comment: Are there roots hanging out the bottom of the pot? whether there are or not, I suggest turning it out of its pot to see if its rootbound, because its giving that general impression...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are over watering this plant.  It is a succulent which stores moisture for periods of dryness.  I would repot this plant in a clay pot about 2 inches larger in diameter.  No larger.  When you water water lightly and definitely allow to dry out before watering again.  Use only potting soil.  No rocks or gravel beneath the soil at the bottom of the pot.  Creates a perched water table that only exacerbates poor drainage.  Do not use city tap water.  I'd go buy some bottled water.  Do not allow any water to remain in a saucer, do not double the pots like this.  I'd get a wider than tall pot, in clay (breathes and is far better for plants sensitive to too much water).  Use Osmocote extended release fertilizer (14-14-14) once per year.  When roots start growing out of the bottom up pot again into a slightly larger pot same as before.  Make sure it is getting bright light, careful with direct sunlight at first.

Comment: And do not plant it any deeper in soil than it is right now.